# Playing module music in Java

Tags: java, audio

How can I play module music (.it, .mod, .xm or .s3m files) in a Java application? (Standard Java for desktop machines)

I tried looking at the open source [JavaMod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javamod/), but it had too many files so I didn't know where to start, and the pre-built .jar file wouldn't even run on my machine.

Comment: This question is much too vague. Simple answer would be: write a module player. Any answer with more detail requires more detail in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Add javamod.jar to the application class path and try with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Helpers.registerAllClasses();
        File music = new File("c:\\test3.XM");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_ISP, "3");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_STEREO, "2");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_WIDESTEREOMIX, "FALSE");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_NOISEREDUCTION, "FALSE");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_NOLOOPS, "FALSE");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_MEGABASS, "TRUE");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_BITSPERSAMPLE, "16");
        props.setProperty(ModContainer.PROPERTY_PLAYER_FREQUENCY, "48000");
        MultimediaContainerManager.configureContainer(props);
        URL modUrl = music.toURI().toURL();
        MultimediaContainer multimediaContainer = MultimediaContainerManager.getMultimediaContainer(modUrl);
        Mixer mixer = multimediaContainer.createNewMixer();
        mixer.startPlayback();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(3);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Works fine for me. But I would also suggest to try running javamod stand-alone in order to make sure it works on your system.

Answer (score 0):

To get JavaMod to run on your machine, you have to run it with the java -jar command.

This screenshot illustrates how to do this:[image]

Comment: I mean playing MODs in a Java application, although running JavaMod itself won't run anyway. Trying to run from the terminal results in a long Java error which ends with a NullPointerException. I'm running OS X in case it might matter, and I'd like a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, cool that JavaMod even exists to play old school modules in Java. I doubt you're going to find much better support these days. Honestly you're best bet is probably going to be to figure out how to call into that library, or just use the source code directly. You'll likely have to look through the code to determine how to integrate with it. By the way, I'm able to run it fine by just double clicking on the .jar file (I'm using Java 6 Update 24 on Windows 7).